# How do you find out which mode changed a keybinding in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I found out when I use gud-gdb, it overrides one of my keybindings. I would like to check which mode changed the keybinding (I know it's probably gud-gdb, but I would still like to know how to check this). I know about C-h k, but is it possible to check which mode set a keybinding?

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>C-h</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, which runs `describe-mode`.  That lists all the keybinds associated with each mode that is currently active.  The keybinding that is getting clobbered will likely be there.

In general, when assigning keys (either as a user or as a mode author) it's best to follow the [Emacs key binding conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).